# Is there anything that prevents this form of use of XOR test?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, xor

Is there anything that prevents this form of use of XOR test?

```
 bool result = false;
 bool b1 = false;
 bool b2 = false;

 ...

 if ( b1 ^ b2 )
 {
    result = true;
 }
```

Comment: Don't want to be rude here... but this is the kind of thing that can be easily tested.

Comment: @ere0n: Actually I think this is pretty implementation-dependent, so I wouldnt say its easily tested.

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: If this is implementation-dependent, then I remove the easily :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would prefer the much clearer:

```
if ( b1 != b2 )
 {
    result = true;
 }
```

Comment: Depends on the context. If you're trying to do an XOR then that's what you should write.

Comment: @Peter The XOR operator is for manipulating bits. There is generally no reason for doing such manipulations with bools.

Comment: Cool. Perfect xor replacement for bools.

Comment: or simply result = (b1 != b2)

Comment: @Alexandre: that's not quite the same. The original retains the previous value of `result` if `b1==b2`, but this doesn't.

Comment: @Alex: `result |= (b1 != b2);`

Answer (score 4):

No, that's perfectly acceptable (if you spell `false` correctly in `bool b2` :]).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if (false ^ false)
    {
        std::cout << "false ^ false" << std::endl;
    }

    if (true ^ false)
    {
        std::cout << "true ^ false" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output: `true ^ false`

Of course, in the example you've provided, you could also do `result = x1 ^ x2` as shorthand.

The other question here is whether there was something preventing you from trying this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's a good idea. The ^ is a bitwise operator not a logical one.
So 1^2 = 3. I'm a bit rusty in C++ but I think bool are stored as unsigned char or something so

```
bool a= 1
bool b = 2
```

is valid.

```
a == true; // yes
b == true; // yes
a ^ b == true; // yes.  not what you are expecting :-(
```

To be sure to use proper true/false values, you have to do something like 
     (!!a) ^ (!!b)

Comment: It's too rusty. A `bool` can be either `true` or `false`, and `true ^ true == false`. Bitrepresentations are (as usual) up to the compiler.

Comment: I'm sure they are still old C++ compiler somewhere which have this behavior ;)